# Update form on same page using Ajax, PHP, MySql

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Need help on this problem.
I have a form being displayed on let's say index.php containing many different fields i.e. drop-down, textfields,...
On the same page, I have a drop-down list containing values coming from my database.
I need to fill in the form based on the value selected from the drop-down list.
Is there a solution for this problem using ajax or even any other way of doing it?
Thanks in advance?

Answer (score 0):

You could listen for changes in the selected dropdown field and make an ajax request to a script that queries the database and returns the desired information in JSON. You'd then have to apply the values to the specified input fields.

Update:
You'll have to figure out the ajax part yourself, but this should get you started. The sample is built using the jquery library.
http://jsfiddle.net/k4emic/4qAE2/2/

Comment: Could you please provide a simple example? I am completely new to JS and jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use javascript/ajax. You can use jQuery for this.

You need something like this:

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
       function changeOptions(value,objId){
            respond = sendRequestToAPHPScript();  // respond is a string that your php script returns; should contain html for the select box.
            ${objId}.innerHTML = respond;
       }
    </script>

    <select id="mySelect" onchange="changeOptions(this.value,'mySelect2');">
      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    </select>

    <select id="mySelect2">
      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    </select>
```

When you change the dropdown value of the first dropdown a javascript function (changeOptions) is called. The function sends a request to your php script, which outputs html with data from your database. The function then fills the other select box with returned html from the request.